# How to make a file in a document library not visible to certain users?

Tags: document-library

We have a set of workbooks that all refer to a master file for data.  What is the best practice way to make the master file accessible by the consuming files but not accessible directly through the document library?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but on the surface I don't think this is possible.  I'm guessing you are referring to multiple xls files that reference other files.  When excel tries to reference the 'master' file, it is doing so via the active user's credentials.  So, that user must be given permissions to the master file.  Since the user has permissions to the master file, they'll also be able to navigate directly to the master file if they know the path.  There are things you could do to make it more difficult for the user to 'find' the master file, but in the end, the user will always be able to view it.